# SQL UPDATE TABLE get the value from 2 table and make calculation and insert one of table

Tags: sql

Example of my issue.

I would like to get the value from table1 and make calculation with table2 value and insert the table2.

FoodList (primary FoodID)

| FoodID | Price |
| --- | --- |
| F001 | 3 |
| F002 | 4 |
| F003 | 7 |
| F004 | 6 |

OrderList (primary OrderID, foreign FoodID)

| OrderID | OrderQty | FoodID | OrderAmt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Q001 | 2 | F001 | 0 |
| Q002 | 4 | F003 | 0 |
| Q003 | 6 | F002 | 0 |
| Q004 | 3 | F004 | 0 |

Expected Result:
OrderAmt = FoodID's Price * OrderQty

| OrderID | OrderQty | FoodID | OrderAmt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Q001 | 2 | F001 | 6 |
| Q002 | 4 | F003 | 28 |
| Q003 | 6 | F002 | 24 |
| Q004 | 3 | F004 | 18 |

I tried:

```
UPDATE OrderList 
  SET OrderAmt =(SELECT f.Price * o.OrderQty FROM FoodList f, OrderList o WHERE f.FoodID = o.FoodID)


UPDATE OrderList o INNER JOIN FoodList f
ON f.FoodID = o.FoodID
SET o.OrderAmt = (f.Price * o.OrderQty)
```

As Solution from @Gordon Linoff:

```
    UPDATE OrderList SET OrderAmt= (SELECT OrderList.OrderQty * fl.Price 
    FROM FoodList fl 
    WHERE fl.FoodID = OrderList.FoodID);
```

Comment: Do you mean `UPDATE <tablename>`, because `ALTER TABLE` is to change the structure of a table (add columns, remove columns, change type, etc)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thank you for the correction. Sorry for making such simple mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `update`.  In most databases, the following should do what you want:

```
update orderlist 
    set orderamt = (select orderlist.orderqty * fl.price
                    from foodlist fl
                    where fl.foodid = orderlist.foodid
                   );
```

If some value are already set, you might want `where o.orderamt is not null` in the outer query.

Comment: Hi this query is work if there are no duplicate FoodID at Orderlist table right? because i put multiple similar FoodID in Orderlist Table cant be query

Comment: @Wai-ChunAng . . . This should work fine for duplicates in `OrderList`.  It won't work with duplicates in `FoodList` . . . but then again, neither would the code in your question.